# Animating/Transitioning elements in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, transition, css-transforms

I have a Users Profile Component, and utilizing `Vue-Router` and `Vuex`, Im able to fetch a users information by grabbing the `username` param in a `router-link` e.g.,`<router-link :to="{name: 'user', params: { username: 'some.username'}}"></router-link>` then in a `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard i make a call to one of my `Vuex` store actions that sends an AJAX requests, grabs the response and stores it in my state, which updates the UI for every User. Pretty straightforward.

However, I now want to perform some subtle transforms/tansitions to some of the UI elements every time the data is changed from user to user, but im confused on how to go about doing so.

**HERE IS MY USER PROFILE COMPONENT**:

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout justify-center>
        <v-flex v-if="user.data">
          <v-avatar :size="100px" >
            <img :src="user.data.img" alt="avatar">
          </v-avatar>
          <p>Hello, You Are {{ user.data.name }}</p>    
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import store from './vuex'
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
  ...
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
   // call vuex ajax action to get user data and update state
  next()
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  // call vuex ajax action to get user data and update state
  next()
  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from , next) {
   // call vuex action to clear user state data
  next()
  }
  computed: {
   ...mapGetters({ user : 'core/user' })
  },
  }
</script>
```

Now, my dilemma is, whenever a new user's data is fetched and the UI is updated, I want to add some subtle transforms/transitions on the `<v-avatar/>` and ` elements, maybe a scale or opacity fade in. Something like this tumblr scale transition:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `<transition></transition>` tag around your `<v-avatar></v-avatar>` tag. Also remember to set a key for your `<v-avatar/>` tag.

For example:

```
<v-avatar :key="user.name.data"></v-avatar>
```

This is to ensure that the transition is triggered on each data change.

More about transitions for Vue can be found at the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html).

Comment: that definitely did it! only bummer is that the elements have to be absolute so they won't interfere with each others space in the flow :(

Comment: @RobertTillman ah, that is the CSS part right? Sorry I cannot help with that. I am quite bad at it. :P